# Add tracking Parameter in front of every link

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-link

I have a question about custom link tagging. I understand, that it is possible with WAC (http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/) to add specific parameters with fixed or variable values to each link in each message via backend configuration. I do also understand that it is possible to make this parameters available for editing in the frontend, but that this is optional.

Now additioanlly I'm searching for a solution to add a dynamic part in FRONT of every single link and not at the end. Like:

1) Tracking Parameter: http://external-prefix?url=

2) URL: http://www.actual-url.com

3) Tracking Parameter: parameter=value

As the value of parameter 1) is dynamic and stored in a data extension I would have something like this:

1) Tracking Parameter: %%=v(@tracking1)=%%

2) URL: http://www.actual-url.com

3) Tracking Parameter: parameter=value

If automatic adding is not possible with the custom link tagging, I would have to add an AMPScript placeholder for this part in front of every single link manually (and use redirectto), which is not ideal from an ux perspective.

So my question is, if it is possible to add a custom parameter in front of every single link with web analytics connector (without a name for the parameter, of course)? If not, do you see another solution?

Any thoughts, ideas or experiences are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Björn

Comment: This is not a capability of WAC - you would likely need to build a custom script or SQL query to create and compile your URLS and store them in a DE that you would then reference in the Email to pull in the completed URL. It sounds much simpler than it is.

Comment: Thanks Gortonington. Do you think that this is somehow possible as a custom backend configuration? Currently I compile my URLs with concat at this seems to be the easiest way, like this:
%%=RedirectTo(Concat(@tracking1, URLEncode('http://www.actual-link.com',1,1),&additionalparam=value))=%%. Anyway it is a mess for a less technical user.

Comment: To a degree, but it would have to be a purely custom build - meaning it will cost lots of hours internally or lots of money for an outside agency to build it.

Comment: I'm not fully following you but I do something like this: http://www.myurl.com?%%=v(@utmstring=%% for adding UTM strings to each url and it works fine. I set my variables at the top of the email template and everything is based on an email name format. So the ampscript looks for the first part of the email name, then the underscore, then the next part of the email name. Why can't you do it like that and also lookup your parameters in a Data extension?

Comment: Thanks for you comment! The only reason is ux and that the guys from the marketing department are not willing / able to write long ampscript code instead of simply adding the link to the template. And indeed it is a bit ugly, as they have to put something in front of the link. Because of that, automatic marketing cloud link redirect does not work without redirectto function.

Comment: I can also confirm not possible. Worked with a Salesforce Architecht for the same use case and nothing really plausible using OOTB functionality

Comment: Thanks Doug. Did you solve it somehow, without OOTB functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with Web Analytics Connector. You’ll probably need to just use `CONCAT` and store the AMPscript in the Global Header.